# Find earliest date in entity in order to calculate number of days between now and then

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have an entity with an attribute `date` which is an NSDate. How would I construct a predicate to get the earliest date stored in the model?

I want to be able to calculate the number of days between now and the earliest date in the entity you see so I can lay them out in a tableview one day at a time. This bit I'm sure I can do myself.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct an `NSExpression` to retrieve the minimum `date`. Something like the following:

```
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"date"];
NSExpression *minDateExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"min:"
    arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
```

You can then wrap this in an `NSExpressionDescription`, call `setPropertiesToFetch:` on your request, and execute it as normal. Instead of returning an array of managed objects, it will now return a dictionary containing the result of your expression—the minimum date.

See the [Fetching Specific Values](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW6) section of Apple's Core Data Programming Guide for a more detailed explanation and sample code.

Comment: good idea, I'll have a look into that. What I'm currently trying is using a sort descriptor to return a sorted list and only fetching one entity. Which is more efficient/better?

Comment: It depends on how many records you have. They would all have to be loaded into memory if you used the sorting approach, which could be slow if there's a lot. You could, however, set the fetch limit to 1—I imagine core data is clever enough to do that at the database level. I'm not sure where expressions are executed; probably on the database, but don't take my word for it. :)

Comment: well yours works. :) I'm setting the fetch limit to 1 in my previous code, but we'll have to see which is better in the long run. There are possibly going to be quite a lot of records, but we'll see how the testing goes. Thanks a lot.